# Diving into Hazelcast newbie's questions

Tags: java, hazelcast

I've recently got a task to evaluate Hazelcast as a key-value store solution for our product. I read their documentation and got a couple of questions here:

1. Regarding Persistence - they say that maps/multimaps can be persistent, which is cool. But how about other collections they provide (lists, queues, sets...)? A piece of configuration code could help a lot here :)
2. I understand that when I get, say, a map from the hazelcast instance, it in fact creates a proxy for me. So any subsequent 'get' request will cause socket communication, assuming that hazelcast is deployed in a standalone mode. Now what about embedded mode? I mean if I have a huge map in RAM of my JVM process, I wouldn't like to get to it through the sockets because of performance...  I hope, it creates some kind of 'local proxy' that goes right into my RAM, Could anyone confirm or disprove this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Currently persistence is supported for only maps. Multimap persistence is not supported but  there is an issue about this: [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/42)

2- Yes, if the entry is located in the local node, there will be no remote call. Also there are more optimization options like near-cache. See [here](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.4/manual/single_html/#MapNearCache)